# how to add ripple effect by using css keyframe in nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to add custom ripple effect in my custom button.

i have a layout

```
<GridLayout row="1" rows="*" columns="*,*"
        class="text-center">

        <StackLayout row="0" col="0" verticalAlignment="center"
            touch="onTouch">
            <Label text="btn1" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout row="0" col="1" verticalAlignment="center"
            touch="onTouch">
            <Label text="btn2" />
        </StackLayout>

    </GridLayout>
```

css

```
StackLayout{
    border-width: 1;
    border-color: #ecf3f8;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #c3edfa;
    color:rgb(44, 23, 23);
    font-size: 18;
    text-align: center;
}




/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Ripple Effect
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

.ripple {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.288);
  animation: rippleEffect 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes rippleEffect {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(10,10);
  } 

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(100,100);
  } 

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0,0);
  }
}
```

js

```
exports.onTouch = function (args) {

  args.object.className = "ripple";

  setTimeout(
    function () {
      args.object.className = "";
    }, 500);

}
```

The animation effect is working fine. 
But the ripple effect is overwriting my background color.
and also the ripple effect is not happening where i touch on button rather it will pop up from center.

the complete demo is here

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=Ds0KtG

Comment: You are overriding the width and height in the CSS class, also setting opacity to zero which will hide it completely. I would suggest going with the [nativescript-material-ripple](https://github.com/Akylas/nativescript-material-components/blob/master/packages/nativescript-material-ripple/README.md)

Comment: @Manoj Thank you, i'm training this to school kids on how to do ripple effect on button. So, That plugin i didn't understood. that's why i raised a question here. Hope you understood.

Comment: I understand but doing it with CSS is overhead. The plugin does it natively with light weight UI controls / graphics. When it comes to apps development, the lighter your controls are, the better your performance is. So using couple layouts, labels, and timeouts just for the shake of ripple effect is bit too much at least when you have the native equivalent.